# React Native info plist in production

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have set up a set of `info.plist` messages in my react-native project, but they are not visible in development environment:

[image]

And only some of them are visible in production environment. Specifically, `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` permission message is not shown in production.

[image] [image]

See? Only Give Meetmeinthe.bar permission to access your photos is visible, not "`Enable Meetmeinthe.bar to access your photo library to upload your profile picture. Any violence, excess of nudity, stolen picture, or scam is forbidden`" that I have included in my app.json file:

```
// other app.json stuff
"infoPlist": {
  "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Turn on location service to allow Meetmeinthe.bar to find the nearest hangouts for you.",
  "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Enable Meetmeinthe.bar to access your photo library to upload your profile picture. Any violence, excess of nudity, stolen picture, or scam is forbidden",
  "NSPushNotificationsDescription": "This will allow Meetmeinthe.bar to send you notifications about new hangouts or chat messages. Also you can disable it in app settings",
  "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Enable Meetmeinthe.bar to access your photo library to upload your profile picture. Any violence, excess of nudity, stolen picture, or scam is forbidden"
}
// other app.json stuff
```

How can I fix this? Why only `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is visible, and only in production?